# Meteor React External JS Files

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-react

I have an HTML template which is bought from [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net), index.html of this template has js files included in the following order:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/helper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/HeadsUp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.swipebox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

How and where should I include these external js files in my Meteor React application?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in this meteor documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html), you can create a `compatibility` folder from on `client`.

> This folder is for compatibility with JavaScript libraries that rely on variables declared with var at the top level being exported as globals. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. These files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.
>
> It is recommended to use npm for 3rd party JavaScript libraries and use import to control when files are loaded.

Comment: This is great. Just to clarify, any js files you put in the client folder will be loaded to the client without having to import them. Anything inside the client folder gets loaded to the client, actually.